# Does process executed from android app have the same rights as android app?

Tags: android, permissions, usb, avrdude

I have granted access to UsbDevice, got his device name (`/dev/bus/usb/002/002`) and passed it to executed process to work with USB device (**avrdude** to be more detailed)

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandArray);
```

and get "**permission denied**" error:

```
W/System.err( 9368): avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/bus/usb/002/002": Permission denied
W/System.err( 9368): ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Invalid argument
```

Avrdude is in the app sandbox (`/data/data/%package%`) so it does not require rooting just to execute avrdude (sure). I believe if i grant access to UsbDevice android app process and all child processes (avrdude) gets access to according USB device file.

Any thoughts? Rooting is undesired.

Comment: UPDATE: app even after getting permission to UsbDevice can't read/write usb device file:

    `File usbDeviceFile = new File(usbDevice.getDeviceName());
        logger.debug("{}exists, canRead={}, canWrite={}", new Object[] {
            usbDeviceFile.exists() ? "" : "NOT ", usbDeviceFile.canRead(), usbDeviceFile.canWrite() });`


returns:

    `D/ArduinoDroid( 2350): device name = /dev/bus/usb/002/002
    D/ArduinoDroid( 2350): exists, canRead=false, canWrite=false`

Comment: Yes, they are the same, but the issue here is that you are trying to use a different API on the native side, for which permission is available to neither the app nor an executable running under its UID.  All but the small handful of permissions implemented at the unix group level (such as networking) are instead actually enablers for APIs based on Binder IPC, and that's not available to a native executable unless you can figure out some way to register it with Binder.

Comment: according to my UPDATE android app itself does not have permission on the file. so it does not make sense to try to access it from child process (avrdude) anyway. not possible?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the Android USB host API is required to access USB devices and you might not be possible to access the device file directly from native code as you would expect on a normal Linux system.

Given this limitation I think there are a couple of possible workarounds. Your ArduinoDroid app will need to read/write USB from Java so the question is how to pass data between avrdude and ArduinoDroid. In my experience a good approach is over a network connection. For example the following avrdude command will program Arduino using localhost at port 6800.

avrdude -v -patmega328p -carduino -Pnet:localhost:6800 -D -Uflash:w:firmware.hex:i

I have done this myself when running avrdude in Linux-on-Android by connecting to my Serial Mirror app and programming Arduino over Bluetooth. I've explained this procedure in this presentation.

http://jeffboody.net/sparkfun-lunch-and-learn-20130124.pdf

The source for my Serial Mirror app is available here as well.

https://github.com/jeffboody/spp-mirror

If invoking avrdude with "exec" does not give network permissions you may need to build avrdude as a library so that it has the same permissions as your app. Sockets are supported for Android native code.

The second option that I can think of would be to provide a JNI interface to avrdude to read/write USB through Java. I think this would be much more difficult since it may require significant changes to avrdude.

Comment: Often cleaner to use a unix domain socket rather than TCP and avoid the need for network permission, but yes.  As for executing vs. linking, Linux-level permissions such as networking will be the same either way as the UID will be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! But all this seems to be useless as i already have uploader written in pure java so it seems to implement stk500 exactly in the same way as avrdude does and it does not work good for some hardware configurations (android device + arduino board). So low-level (file access) seems to be what i need

Comment: I had not thought of domain sockets but you will probably have to hack avrdude to replace TCP sockets.

Comment: Can you give some more details about the kind of problems you are seeing for the Java implementation of avrdude? Have you confirmed that those Android devices support USB Host mode?

Comment: i've implemented stk500 for uploading and works great for my hardware configuration (any of 2 devices and any of 3 my arduino boards), but for some users the bootloader just don't reply within 1000ms. i've viewed avrdude source code and used its tricks like doubl dtr/rts and triple sync attempt. the problem seems to be in Android USB API so i just want to use low-level USB access

Comment: i've found function to return file descriptor which can be passed to native code http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.html#getFileDescriptor(). Does anyone know how to use it?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is on the Android side?   Have you taken into account the USB protocol difference between the Uno with its Atmega 'u' interface and older/clone boards with FTDI chips?  Also unclear you have verified true host mode support on the problem devices.

Comment: Not sure, but it can be uploaded from pc without any problems and sometimes we have problems on android. Yes, i have dumped interaction between avrdude and th boards and reproduced it on andorid using pure java code. I don't have problem devices so i just want to let the users possibility to select uploader

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the file descriptor you can pass it to native with JNI.

// java

private native void NativePassFd(int fd);

// c

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_MyName_MyPackage_MyClass_NativePassFd(JNIEnv* env, jobject  obj, jint fd);

From the native code you should be able to use read/write functions. These should behave the same as fread/fwrite except they will use the fd instead of a FILE pointer. It is important that the fd is invalid in another process (except when passed by special mechanisms such as Android's Binder mechanism.

ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);

ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);

Comment: it's better to generate header using `javah` utility to avoid errors